# Potential ambiguities in function Limit (Generate explicit conditions on parameters)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I evaluate the following expression with Mathematica 11:

```
L = Limit[-x^2/(y - Sqrt[y^2 + 2 x^2]), x -> 0]
```

This yields the incorrect answer $L=0$ rather than the conditional expression: $L=y$ for $y>0$ and $L=0$ otherwise. Including the assumption $y>0$ yields the correct answer though.

Why is there no warning by *Mathematica* that the solution might not be general?

Comment: Might be a problem in `Series`, which is used by `Limit`. Will investigate.

Comment: Okay, I see what is the underlying issue. We have to invert the series `SeriesData[x, 0, {y - Sqrt[y^2], 0, -(1/Sqrt[y^2])}, 0, 4, 1]`. The leading ocefficient is checked to see if it is zero, in effect using `PossibleZeroQ`. That returns that it is not zero (because generically it is not zero-- unfortunately in this case, it is also not  generically nonzero, but that's how PZQ works). The rest follows from there. Moral: if/when such things are affected by assumptions, provide those assumptions. Setting `GenerateConditions-> True` in `Limit` can also help, as of version 11.2

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about the option [`GenerateConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateConditions.html)`-> True`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[l, x, y];
l = Limit[
  x^2/(-y + Sqrt[2 x^2 + y^2])
  , x -> 0
  , GenerateConditions -> True
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, this resolves the issue.

Comment: Also note that is an answer which is valid except on the positive reals and the imaginary axis.  If you want to see the range for reals, use  `Limit[-x^2/(y - Sqrt[y^2 + 2 x^2]), x -> 0,  GenerateConditions -> True, Assumptions -> y \[Element] Reals]`, which will tell you it is zero as long as `y!=0`.